# RegEx replacing first occurrence in the token only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the follow case: imagine you want to pre-apend a prefix `THIS` in a className. and you have the follow possible examples:

```
.class-name .class-name-whatever {}
.class-name-other {}
```

I'm using the follow RegExp and works great

```
return text.replace(new RegExp('class-name', 'g'),`THIS.class-name`);
```

output

```
THIS.class-name THIS.class-name-whatever {}
THIS.class-name-other {}
```

GREAT, but here is the problem:

if I have `.class-name.class-name-other` I would like to end with `THIS.class-name.class-name-other` instead of `THIS.class-nameTHIS.class-name-other` how can I target only the first occurrence of `.class-name`.

I have searched in other RegExp but cant find a solution.

--- UPDATE ---------

Maybe I wasn't really clear in my question sorry about that.
I need to use `g` cause I'm searching and replacing an entire chunk of text as example:

Look the follow example `.example.example--black` will end as `THIS.example.THIS.example--black` and should `THIS.example.example--black`

input:

`.example {min-width: 20rem;padding: 2.5rem 0; }
.example .example__line--extra-space {display: block;margin-top:1.5625rem;}
.example .example__copyright a {border: 0; }
.example.example--black a {color: white; }
.example.example--black h3 {color: white; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 46em) {
.example .example__list--connect .example__connect__link {height: 2.625rem; width: 2.625rem; }
.example .example__list--connect .example__connect__link img {width: 1rem; vertical-align: middle; } }`

**Should add `THIS` at the end of processing. to each of .example ocurrence.**

Comment: get rid of the 'g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `/(\.\s*example\s*[^{]*{)/`
Replace `THIS$1`

Answer (score 0):

The `'g'` modifier stands for "global". Just lose it, and the regexp will be applied on the first match only:

```
return text.replace(new RegExp('class-name'),`THIS.class-name`);
// HERE -----------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your regex to the following:

```
/class-name.*/g
```

Which is a greedy regex, `.` matches everything but a newline:

```
text.replace(/class-name.*/g, 'THIS.$&');
```

`/.../` is a regex construct. Also note that `$&` refers to the whole matched string